# Making R package and includes Jar files in

Tags: r, rjava

I use RStudio to make my package. The idea is one of the functions in my R file runs a jar file using System(). it works fine using Rstudio. The problem comes with distribution. when I use devtools::install_github("package on github"). it ignores my jar file, and it doesn't download it with the rest of the package files.

I appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: You may want to look into rJava, as the preferred way to use Java code without relying on `system()`.

Comment: You have not provided how you have your package organized. If it's on GH then perhaps include a repo link as well.

Comment: Other packages that successfully include jars in their packaging: [`RSQLServer`](https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer) and [`rkafkajars`](https://github.com/cran/rkafkajars) (for [`rkafka`](https://github.com/cran/rkafka)). I successfully `install_github`ed (is that a verb?) `RSQLServer` and the jar part works fine.

Comment: github.com/monmon-2007/Images2